# Output not as expected in Racket

Tags: output, racket

I ran this code and I don't understand how the output is `2`? As far as I'm concerned the output should always be `1`?

Code:

```
(define (count p l)
  (if (empty? l)
      0
      (if (p (first l))
          (+l (count p (rest l)))
          (count p (rest l)))))

(define (ident x)
  x)

(count ident '(#true #true #false))
```

Comment: Use copy and paste when you insert your code samples. You have replaced the the letter l with the number 1 - so the program won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `count` counts the number of elements in the list that satisfy the predicate `p`. Since you are using `ident` as the predicate, we have that `(ident #true) = #true` and `(ident #false) = #false` does not. This means that you have two values in your example list that are counted. This matches the result 2.

Comment: what is ident actually doing? Is it just the list, and what is with the second #true in the list?

Comment: Use the repl. Try some examples such as `(ident 1)`  `(ident "foo")` and others. Tip: `ident` is short for `identity`.

Comment: And what do you mean by "what is with the second #true in the list"?

Comment: Of `count p l` what is actually `p` and `l`? I thought `p = list` and `l` remains empty?

Comment: p stands for predicate, l stands for list

Answer (score 1):

First, you have used the number `1` instead of the letter `l` for the list, so your code will not even run the way it is. After fixing that to:

```
(define (count p l)
  (if (empty? l)
      0
      (if (p (first l))
          (+ 1 (count p (rest l)))
          (count p (rest l)))))
```

you should get an output of `2`, as you noticed, because the procedure is essentially counting up by one whenever `(p (first l))` evaluates to true. And it holds that:

```
> (if #true 1 0)
1
> (if #false 1 0)
0
```

so for the list `'(#true #true #false)`, the procedure will count up twice, hence the result being `2`.

Comment: I worked around with it and somehow get it now. I just don't understand what `p` is? `l = list` right?

Comment: Yes, it is. And `p` is being used in this function as a [predicate](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)).